# Gentzen systems and natural deduction

Tags: mathematical-logic

I write a chapter for my book in logic concerning Gentzen systems and natural deduction. I read the paper of Gentzen and I realized that his motivation was to create a system that works as close as to human reasoning .... In my current book version, I present first Gentzen systems, and then the natural deduction, but after all this info I wonder if I have to present natural deduction first. What is your opinion about this? If there are some classical references I don't know, please let me know. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: A good source cab be F.Pelletier, [A Brief History of Natural Deduction (2010)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/014453499298165) as well as Jan von Plato, [GENTZEN'S PROOF SYSTEMS BYPRODUCTS IN A WORK OF GENIUS (2012)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1344861886). Also : Irving Anellis, [Forty years of unnatural natural deduction and quantification : A history of first-order systems of natural deduction from Gentzen to Copi (1991)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rml/1204902659).

Comment: Usually, ND is much easier to grasp than sequent calculus. See e.g. Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=8RUOAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2013).